# How to resolve the conflict of onClickListener and setTouchListener in FrameLayout?

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I have a FrameLayout which contains a TextView, I add OnTouchListener to the FrameLayout to do translateX job. And then I add OnClickListener to the TextView to change the text. Then the FrameLayout cannot translateX.

How to resolve this conflict? I want the TextView can perform click operator and the FrameLayout can translateX.

Can any one help me? Thanks you!

The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then in the Activity

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    float downX = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_frame);

        FrameLayout panel = findViewById(R.id.panel);
        panel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        downX = event.getX();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float dx = event.getX() - downX;
                        panel.setTranslationX(dx);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("this is textview click");
            }
        });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `match_parent` attribute on your TextView which is taking the entire space available for it. Change the from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` and it should function fine.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your trigger for the FrameLayout is hidden behind the TextView as the TextView has taken over all the available space to it.

Comment: Thanks,  this maybe a method in my case. If the TextView has almost space of the FrameLayout ( e.g. Textview's width is match_parent and height is 50% of the FrameLayout), how to deal with this case? @Nero

Comment: e.g. FrameLayout's height is 500dp,  TextView's width is match_parent, TextView's height is 250dp. In this case, I touch in Textview and move, the FrameLayout is not translate X. @Nero

Comment: @user3812074 where exactly are you clicking on the FrameLayout? If the height of the TextView is 50%, you should be clicking outside of the 50%, right? For testing purposes, I would recommend you to change your TextView to a Button (this way you can visually see the space occupied by the Button) and then try clicking the Button and FrameLayout. Hopefully, it should behave as you'd expect it to.

Comment: Thanks~ Maybe I don't describe the question clear. I change TextView to Button, and I want to perform Button click action when I click on Button（finger Down then Up）, when I slip on Button (finger Down on Button , the Move finger for a distance, the Up), I want the FrameLayout can translate X. @Nero

Comment: @user3812074 so just that I understand this... when pressing the button and performing ACTION_MOVE, setTranslationX() method is also triggered?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to get the textView visible Rect

```
Rect visibleRect = new Rect();
yourTextView.getGlobalVisibleRect();
```

and then you check your touch event coordinates,

```
if (event.getX()>= visibleRect.left and event.getX()<=visibleRect.right and 
   event.getY>=visibleRect.bottom and event.getY<= visibleRect.top)
   {
   //perform click on textView
   return
   }
```

Comment: Thanks~ According to your answer, it means that if I have multi-child view in FrameLayout, I have to check every childview's rect? @Ahmed.ess

Comment: @user3812074 yes because android check touch event in parent view before childs, so if you have a touch in your parent you will never get onClick on child,
i think that its the only solution